# Total internal reflection (reflection of 2 fish underwater)

Tags: optics

Question:
A fish lives at the bottom of a lake 10m deep filled with water whose index of refraction 1.52.

a) At what angle relative to the normal must the fish look up towards the surface of the water in order to see a fisherman who is sitting on a distant shore?

b)What is the closest that another fish living at the bottom of the lake can approach in order that the first fish can see it by looking towards the surface?

Actually my  question is only for part (b). I found this answer in the internet[image]

Why is it [sin(theta) = 10/(d/2)]? since for the right angled triangle, 10 is the adjacent and d/2 is the opposite!!?[image]

Comment: your 10m is drawn wrongly, and d/2 is hypotenuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d/2$ is the "opposite" side relative to $\theta_c$, and the depth ($D = 10$ m) is the "adjacent" side, so $tan(\theta_c)=(d/2)/D$.  Thus $d = 17.47$ m.